# Is this the right way to have a responsive navigation menu?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I'm working on a website and it's my first time making a responsive one so I'm having a little trouble.

I have a navigation menu which I want to collapse to a hamburger icon (the three horizontal bars) when at a certain screen size. At the moment I have something like this with a normal navigation menu and another dropdown version for mobile that change place with each other:

```
<div id="normalnavigation">
  <ul>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
    <li>Link 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="mobilenavigation">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="Hamburger Icon Here" />
      <ul>
        <li>Line 1</li>
        <li>Link 2</li>
        <li>Link 3</li>
      </ul>
    <li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then in the css, something like this:

```
#mobilenavigation { display:none }

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #mobilenavigation { 
    display:inherit
  }
  #normalnavigation {
    display:none
  }
}
```

As for as the above code is concerned, everything works properly. But I'm wondering if this is the right way to go about doing all this? And if so, I cant seem to figure out the css code that I would need for the dropdown mobile menu to work. - so I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: A lot of times you don't need to create two separate menus. What you need to do is use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) control the styling of elements at various breakpoint (screen sizes), i.e. hide/show display inline vs block.

Comment: Here is a super basic example based on your provided markup, [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsghkLzo/). Resize the window to see the layout changes in the navigation.

Comment: @hungerstar Thanks, but how would i get the links to be hidden until the user hovers/presses on the menu icon? And without the links disturbing the rest of the layout?

Comment: You'd have to use JS to hide/show or CSS and absolute positioning so they don't take up space. Technically you could hide/show with CSS but the implementation of the CSS selectors and markup is a bit too restrictive for me.